# clear meaning of .* in regex

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

`.` means match any character in regular expressions.
`*` means zero or more occurrences of the SINGLE regex preceding it.
My `alphabet.txt` contains a line

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Doesn't `grep a.*z alphabet.txt` mean match any substrings that start with `a`, with zero or more occurrences of any type of SINGLE character in between them, and end with `z`? For example, `abz`, `abbz`, `ahhhhhz`, but not `abbdz`?

I thought `grep a.*z alphabet.txt` wouldn't catch the line in my alphabet file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` means that the immediately-preceding pattern is repeated, not that the matched text is repeated. For example, `[ab]*` means `(|[ab]|[ab][ab]|[ab][ab][ab]|…)` The pattern `[ab]` is repeated zero or more times. It will match `"aba"` because that properly fulfills the pattern `[ab][ab][ab]`.

With `.*`, it becomes `(|.|..|...|....|…)`, so it matches any number of characters, and the characters can differ.

Answer (score 0):

In `abbdz`, just because `.` matched `b` at first doesn't mean `.` will only match `b` for the rest of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Repetition modifiers such as `*` act on the preceding regex atom, **not** on *repeats of the character matched by* the preceding regex atom. So for example:

```
$ printf 'az\nabz\nabbz\nabbbz\nabcz\n' | sed -n '/a.*z/p'
az
abz
abbz
abbbz
abcz
```

(all lines match). If you want to only match repeats of the *matched* character, you can use a backreference:

```
$ printf 'az\nabz\nabbz\nabbbz\nabcz\n' | sed -n '/a\(.\)\1*z/p'
abz
abbz
abbbz
```

Comment: How could you also match the first line, `az`? I tried `'/a\(.|\(.\)\1*\)z/ p'`, but got an error, "Invalid back reference". `'/a\(.\)?\1*z/ p'` also didn't work.

Comment: Remember `|` also needs to be escaped in BRE - so either `sed -n '/a\(.\|\)\1*z/p'` or (more readable, using ERE) `sed -En '/a(.|)\1*z/p'`

Comment: Thanks! I just found another answer myself: `sed -n '/a\(.\)\?\1*z/ p'`, or `sed -En '/a(.)?\1*z/ p'`

Comment: @wjandrea yup that's neater than my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

`grep a.*z` matches everything between the first occurrence of a and the last occurrence of z, including the first a and the last z. The `.*` is a wildcard expression that matches any sequence of characters including an empty sequence of length=0. `grep a.*z` matches all of the following strings that start with a and end  with z: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "abz", "abbz", "ahhhhhz" and "abbdz". It also matches text that spans multiple lines, for example this text:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abz
abbz
ahhhhhz
abbdz
```